# nullPointerExcepction while accesing setter (Android)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have user object in which one of the members is an arraylist, i created an instance pf this user and while trying to set new array list it keeps crushing "Attempt to invoke virtual method Classes.User.setUser_stocks_array(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference"

Activity 1:

```
private User localUser;
localUser = new User("", email);

String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(localUser);
Intent loginUserIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StockListActivity.class);
                                    loginUserIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_USER_FROM_LOGIN", jsonString);
startActivity(loginUserIntent);
```

activity 2:

```
    public User gsonReturnUser(String jsonInString){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        User tmpUser = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, User.class);

        Stock s1 = new Stock("hsdsf", "aa", 15, 20, "yes 4");
        Stock s2 = new Stock("cvcx", "aa", 25, 50, "yes fgfd");
        Stock s3 = new Stock("asd", "aa", 45, 54, "yes fdg");
        Stock s4 = new Stock("uiudf", "aa", 75, 98, "yes cv");

        ArrayList<Stock> tmpList = new ArrayList<Stock>();
        tmpList.add(0, s1);
        tmpList.add(1, s2);
        tmpList.add(2, s3);
        tmpList.add(3, s4);

        tmpUser.setUser_stocks_array(tmpList);

        return tmpUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stock_list);
        String userFromLogin = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_USER_FROM_LOGIN");
        localUser = gsonReturnUser(userFromLogin);
        stockList =  localUser.getUser_stocks_array();
}
```

my Setter:

```
public void setUser_stocks_array(ArrayList<Stock> user_stocks_array) {
    this.user_stocks_array = user_stocks_array;
}
```

why is this happening?
Thanks!

***update:***
my first activity was not launched properly that is the reason for the nullPointerException.

Comment: `fromJson` can return `null`, which you don't handle.

Comment: run in a debugger and look at the values of your variables. A good candidate would be that `jsonInString` is not what you think it is. A typical reason could be a typo in the name of the constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your tmpUser object may be getting a null response from gson.fromJson() method.

Comment: you right, it is null, what may be the reason for it to be null?

Comment: For that I don't know because I never used this Gson library. I prefer to parse JSON objects using native classes from Android.

Answer (score 0):

next time, I suggest using parcelable instead of json string to sending a objec